# custom button in wpf with path as content

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I create a custom button control which takes the argument of path in the button constructor so i can reuse the control throughout my projects?

This is how i normally create buttons....

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonPathStyle}" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Fill="Gray" Data="M50,50 L100,100 L150,50" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

---

However I would like to create a custom button so i could create them like this along with a custom style sheet

```
<Grid>
    <PathButton Width="24" Height="24"
                Data="M50,50 L100,100 L150,50"  
                Stretch="Uniform" />
</Grid>
```

If anyone knows of any good resources of can even whip together a quick example it'd be greatly appreciated. I would assume creating the button would be pretty simple as a custom control.

And by custom control i mean compile into a DLL i can share.

Comment: Did you try googling "WPF custom control"?  All the required information is readily available.

Comment: Adding arguments to your custom control constructor is not advised ! I suggest create your own custom button by creating new class named PathButton inheriting from Button control of WPF, then add dependency properties See more about it at msdn => https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Behind:

```
    public class PathButton : Button
{
    public static DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Geometry), typeof(PathButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

    public Geometry Data
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PathButton thisClass = (PathButton)o;
        thisClass.SetData();
    }

    private void SetData()
    {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = Data;
        path.Stroke = this.Foreground;
        path.StrokeThickness = 1;
        this.Content = path;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:PathButton Data="M50,50 L100,100 L150,50" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
 public class LazyButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Geometry), typeof(LazyButton), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataChanged)));

    private static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LazyButton button = d as LazyButton;
        button.Content = new Path() { Data = e.NewValue as Geometry, Fill = Brushes.Gray, Stretch = Stretch.Uniform };
    }
    public Geometry Data
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This is usable in xaml:

```
        <local:LazyButton Data="M50,50 L100,100 L150,50"></local:LazyButton>
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to make the Fill and Stretch options settable in xaml as well